# Unable to add field - schema lock

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I was going to add a field to my polygon layer for obtaining the area of the polygon and got an error message shown below. Never encountered this before - what is going on here?

[image]

Comment: Is the file open in any other ESRI software, e.g. another mxd or ArcCatalog? I so, close them. If it still ain't working, close all ESRI applications and restart only the one mxd you are working in.

Comment: If it is not the above, then if you have been running Python scripts from IDLE or another IDE then close that too.

Answer (score 5):

From ArcGIS [Rules for working with schema locks](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00210000000p000000):

> A schema is the structure or design of a database or database object such as a feature class or table. A schema lock means that another application is accessing a database, and you are not allowed to alter its structure by adding or removing fields.

As Martin and PolyGeo noted in comments above, if the file is open in any other Esri software -- ArcCatalog, another instance of ArcMap, or Python -- that is causing the schema lock. If shutting down all ArcGIS software and restarting ArcMap doesn't release it, then you may need to reboot the computer.

A schema lock can also occur if your data is on a network or in an SDE database, althouhg yours appears to be on the C: drive so that is probably not the case here. If that does occur, however, then you need to contact other users who may be viewing the data and ask them to stop.

Comment: yes it was open in ArcCatalogue

Answer (score 1):

You need to close any other software that has access to your table before you can edit it.